# ObservePoint & Hubscan

Tags: software-testing, analytics

I am in process of Researching about the Testing involved in Google Analytics. I came up with two resources.

1. Hubscan
2. ObservePoint

But couldn't find informative link anywhere about these resources. If anyone has used these tools before or using it now, can you please here know if there are resources available.

Comment: Sorry, asking about drawbacks for program X is not on-topic here. Please read the [what can I ask here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [quality duidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), and maybe [tool X versus Y](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question). Are you looking for software, then [edit] your question and give your requirements. If not, delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**- ObservePoint**

• *Cannot use it for multiple clients 
• Buy it for 15k US $
• If you want to run for 2 clients may be top up is required upon licence
• External link tracking works only sometimes*

**- HubScan**

• *Buy the licence for 25k-30k US $ if you want it for multiple clients
• Report is not friendly
• The extension available in Chrome is not full featured
• Need to provide the client domain when required to Audit. So that the support        team adds the client url's in database*